# How do you define a constructor in Java?

Tags: java, object, constructor, compiler-errors, undefined

I'm new to Java so I'm not sure what exactly is the problem with my code. I keep on getting a Unresolved compilation problem: The constructor Student() is undefined. I have been working on it for hours now but I'm not sure what the problem is. I would appreciate the help. Thanks!
[image: This is the main class]
[image: Here is the Student class]

Comment: Your constructor is defined correctly, but expects parameters.  Your main class is not passing any parameters to the constructor. (Also, it's best to include your code as text, not as an image)

Comment: Thanks! where would I place the parameters? Student beststudent = new Student(inside here?);

Comment: Jorge, see the questions below and mark the one that solved your problem, they've already answered that question :)

Comment: Oracle's tutorial already has all the basic information you need: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html

Answer (score 1):

You created your constructor correctly:

```
public Student (String n, char g, Date b, Preference p){
     name = n;
     gender = g;
     birthDay = b;
     pref = p;
}
```

However, this constructor **only works with all of those arguments given.** You're trying to make a Student object with no parameters into the constructor. This case is called the *default constructor*.

To make such a constructor, you'd do:

```
public Student (){
     //some default initializations
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are instantiating a student using

```
new Student()
```

Which is wrong because you have not yet defined a constructor that takes no parameters.

You can fix it by either defining a new constructor

```
public Student(){
   //Set default values here
}
```

Or by using the constructor you already have.

```
Student bestStudent = new Student("Bryan", 'm', ...);
```

Answer (score 1):

Java provides a default constructor for a class when you do not define one ( in this case Student() ) . However, since defined the constructor Student( String s, char c, Date d, Preference p ) this default constructor is not automatically provided.

You now have to either use the constructor you specified. Or implement an constructor in the Student class that accepts no parameters

```
public Student() { }
```

You can use this to call the other constructor with your default variables.

```
public Student() {

     this("", '', null, null); //Assuming you code is made to handle such a situation
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling new Student() with no arguments. This is called a default constructor. You don't have to specify a default constructor if there are no other constructors. But if you have another constructor that takes arguments, then you have to specify it.

You simply need to add this to your Student class.

```
public Student(){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a value for `n`, `g`, `b`, `p`.

So `new Student("hi", 'a', new Date(), myPreference)`

Answer (score 0):

Add another constructor that is called a [no-argument constructor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nullary_constructor) to your student class. Because in the `for` loop you are using one without any arguments. And you have not defined it in the Student class.

Simply add the following lines.

```
public Student() {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when you initialize your variables in Student() they should have modifiers:

`private String name;`
`private char gender;`
`private Boolean matched;`

etc; this might be the cause for your error.

Answer (score 0):

Example: If you have class with name Main
So you can define constructor for this class Like:

```
Main(){

}
```

For more details about constructors please refer to [this link](http://codebun.com/constructor-in-java-interview-questions-answers/).

Comment: Are you affiliated with the site you've linked? You appear to have also linked to it in [another answer](//stackoverflow.com/a/52675856), under a different account. If you are affiliated, you *must disclose the affiliation*. If you don't disclose affiliation, it's considered spam. See: [**What signifies "Good" self promotion?**](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212), [some tips and advice about self-promotion](/help/promotion), [What is the exact definition of "spam" for Stack Overflow?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260638), and [What makes something spam](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035).